# Single Threaded SynchronizationContext

Tags: c#, async-await, synchronizationcontext

There is an async method in my server that I want to always run (with the caller not waiting for it, just dispatching) on a dedicated thread, not from the ThreadPool. I found some implementations for a single-threaded SynchronizationContext, but they seem untested and I'd like to use a more stable one.

I found Nito AsyncEx's [AsyncContext](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext&referringTitle=Documentation), but I haven't been able to figure out if it could run on a single dedicated thread through the whole application lifecycle.

Does anyone know if AsyncContext could fit my requirement? Or, do you know a tested and stable implementation for a single-threaded SynchronizationContext?

Comment: Getting code to run on a specific thread requires solving the [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).  The simplest solution to it is a thread-safe queue with a loop that retrieves jobs from the queue.  A "job" can simply be an Action delegate.

Comment: Why do you need a single threaded sync context?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a synchronization context - there's a task scheduler that can do exactly what you need - `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair`.

Basically, you'll schedule all your tasks to the exclusive scheduler in the pair, and it will all process sequentially in a separate thread.

Comment: So that would be something like `MyAsyncMethod().Start(scheduler.ExclusiveScheduler);` when always using the same instance of `scheduler`? Will that always happen on the same thread?

Comment: @mot If it's actually asynchronous, rather than just parallel, probably something more like either `ContinueWith` or `ConfigureAwait` but yeah, that's the idea. You shouldn't really return non-started `Task`s from methods, that's just asking for trouble :D